# I want to fetch birthdate from Yahoo's API

Tags: asp.net, yahoo, yahoo-api

I am using the Yahoo API, but I am not getting the birth dates of my contacts. What do I do?

I am making an application in asp.net, and I want the birth dates to be fetched also.
This is part of the JSON string I get:

```
created": "2012-04-16T16:08:30Z",
"updated": "2012-04-16T16:08:30Z",
"uri": "http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/RB5EYES5SQ6HZ22ZIHCJ5EIY5E/contact/33554861",
     "isConnection": "false",
     "id": "33554861",
     "fields": {
      "created": "2012-04-16T16:08:30Z",
      "updated": "2012-04-16T16:08:30Z",
      "uri": "http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/RB5EYES5SQ6HZ22ZIHCJ5EIY5E/contact/33554861/email/33555114",
      "id": "33555114",
      "type": "email",
      "value": "accounts@timeseo.com",
      "editedBy": "OWNER"
```